# Encrypt Decrypt VS MySQL

Tags: php, encryption, single-sign-on

I have two website and I need them to save user's state and communicate each other in the client side.

The only method that I can think right now is :

1. Website A save the current user state in database (which is MySQL in this case), then give the user a unique key to be verified later at Website B
2. Website A save the current user state in Encrypted key that will be given to the user and then verified later at Website B

In short, which one is the best? should I user Encrypt & Decrypt or save it at MySQL instead?

Comment: You could benefit from reading about OAuth 2.0 even if you don't want to use that because option 2 is essentially a bearer token while option 1 is like an access token (not sure what the correct terminology is here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you want to achieve is web SSO (single-sign-on).

My opinion is that you are trying to invent a wheel doing that very customized /hardcoded way.

As an answer - both ways will work, I'd prefer number 2 (e.g. application A could provide a signed/encrypted JWT token which could be validated by app B). In that case there's no dependency on DB schema.

Maybe you could consider using a common IdP (identity provider) using OAuth or SAML which would allow you to build single sign-on between other (maybe not yet foreseen) application standardized way.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer